# R extract multiple variables from column

Tags: r, extract, tidyr

I'm new to R so my apologies if this is unclear.

My data contains 1,000 observations of 3 variable columns: (a) person, (b) vignette, (c) response. The vignette column contains demographic information presented in a paragraph, including age (20, 80), sex (male, female), employment (employed, not employed, retired), etc. Each person received a vignette that randomly presented one of the values for age (20 or 80), sex (male or female), employment (employed, not employed, retired), etc.

(e.x. Person #1 received: A(n) 20 year old male is unemployed. Person #2 received: A(n) 80 year old female is retired. Person #3 received: A(n) 20 year old male is unemployed... Person # 1,000 received: A(n) 20 year old female is employed.)

I'm trying to use **tidyr:extract** on (b) vignette to extract the rest of the demographic information and create several new variable columns labeled "age", "sex" "employment" etc. So far, I've only been able to extract "age" using this code:

`tidyr::extract(data, vignette, c("age"), "([20:80]+)")`

I want to extract all of the demographic information and create variable columns for (b) age, (c) sex, (d) employment, etc. My goal is to have 1,000 observation rows with several variable columns like this:

```
(a) person, (b) age, (c) sex, (d) employment (e) response 
Person #1       20      Male       unemployed     Very Likely
Person #2       80      Female     retired        Somewhat Likely
Person #3       20      Male       unemployed     Very Unlikely
...
Person #1,000  20      Female     employed       Neither Likely nor Unlikely
```

Vignette Example:

```
structure(list(Response_ID = "R_86Tm81WUuyFBZhH", Vignette = "A(n) 18 year-old Hispanic woman uses heroin several times a week. This person is receiving welfare, is employed and has no previous criminal conviction for drug possession. - Based on this description, how likely or unlikely is it that this person has a drug addiction?", Response = "Very Likely"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I appreciate any guidance or help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please could you share some examples from your vignette variable? We can help but some data is necessary.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` i.e `dput(head(data))`.

Comment: My apologies, I'm a novice and don't know how to add my data. If it helps, it's named "out" in my RStudio environment.

Comment: Run `dput(head(out))` in the console copy the output here.

Comment: It's "too long by 1,442 characters". Can I DM it to you?

Comment: Then just show us 1 row - `dput(head(out, 1))`

Comment: structure(list(Response_ID = "R_86Tm81WUuyFBZhH", Vignette = "A(n) 18 year-old Hispanic woman uses heroin several times a week. This person is receiving welfare, is employed and has no previous criminal conviction for drug possession. - Based on this description, how likely or unlikely is it that this person has a drug addiction?", 
    Response = "Very Likely"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: Well, your first case itself doesn't have "male"/"female". It has "woman".

Comment: Don't put the result from `dput(head(out, 1))` in the _comments_.  Please _edit_ the post and put it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made up some regex's to pull out your info.  Experience shows that you're going to spend many hours tweaking the regex before you get anything reasonably satisfactory.  E.g. you won't pull the employment status correctly out of a sentence like "Neither she nor her boyfriend are *employed*"

```
raw <- structure(list(Response_ID = "R_86Tm81WUuyFBZhH", 
                      Vignette = "A(n) 18 year-old Hispanic woman uses heroin several times a week. This person is receiving welfare, is employed and has no previous criminal conviction for drug possession. - Based on this description, how likely or unlikely is it that this person has a drug addiction?", 
                      Response = "Very Likely"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
raw2 <- raw %>% 
  add_row(Response_ID = "R_xesrew",
               Vignette = "A 22 year-old White boy drinks bleach.  He is unemployed",
               Response = "Unlikely")


rzlt <- raw2 %>% 
  tidyr::extract(Vignette, "Age", "(?ix) (\\d+) \\s* year\\-old", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  tidyr::extract(Vignette, "Race", "(?ix) (hispanic|white|asian|black|native \\s* american)", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  tidyr::extract(Vignette, "Job", "(?ix) (not \\s+ employed|unemployed|employed|jobless)", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  tidyr::extract(Vignette, "Sex", "(?ix) (female|male|woman|man|boy|girl)", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  select(- Vignette)
```

Gives

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  Response_ID       Sex   Job        Race     Age   Response   
  <chr>             <chr> <chr>      <chr>    <chr> <chr>      
1 R_86Tm81WUuyFBZhH woman employed   Hispanic 18    Very Likely
2 R_xesrew          boy   unemployed White    22    Unlikely
```

Save your work

```
library(readr)
write_csv(rzlt, "myResponses.csv")
```

Alternatively

```
library(openxlsx)
openxlsx::write.xlsx(rzlt, "myResponses.xlsx", asTable = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However, this is only for Person #1. I need to include all 1,000 persons and account for their unique vignette demographic info. In other words, is it possible to include all 1,000 observations/persons and their particular value for "Sex", "Job", "Age", etc? For this do you need the entire dput output, rather than just row 1?

Comment: I edited my response.  I added another row.  You can see it works multi-row.  If it's good for 2 it should be good for 1000.

Comment: Awesome. The last thing I need help with is saving the eventual 1,000x6 tibble as a csv file so I can open it in excel. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: I know you're new; not long ago I was too.  A little StackOverlfow etiquette: if somebody's answered a question for you, #ACCEPT# their answer.  You do that by clicking the gray checkmark (upper left of the post) and turning it green.  You can also upvote a post with the arrows above the check. ALSO, you can upvote comments.  E.g., if @ronak-shah 's comments helped you understand something, you should upvote them too.

Comment: When I run `write_csv(rzlt, "myResponses.csv")` I get: Error in write_csv(rzlt, "myResponses.csv") : could not find function "write_csv". When I try `write.csv(rzlt, "myResponses.csv")` I get: Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'rzlt' not found. My apologies for being such a novice.

Comment: I added code which sets `rzlt`; it's in the first block of code; use your browser's _search_ if it doesn't jump out at you.  Also, I added the library call for `readr` so that you find `write_csv`.  Hint:  If you're in RStudio, type `?? write_csv` to see if `write_csv` is available in a package.

Comment: Got it to work! Thank you SO much. I will be back if I run into any more problems.

Comment: I have two more questions about extracting. (1) How do I extract two specific words from my vignette? For example, extract "a previous" or "no previous" for my criminal conviction column. (2) How do I extract either 1 word or 2 words? For example, extract "receiving" or "not receiving" for my welfare column. Thanks again.

Comment: If you have a problem, use a Regular Expression (regex) https://xkcd.com/1171/

Comment: `str_match(text, "(?ix)  (a|no) \\s+ previous")` and `str_match(text, "(?ix) (not \\s+)? receiving")`  *not run*  Reference : https://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html#matching-patterns-with-regular-expressions

Comment: Actually, you may do better using `str_extract` than `str_match`.  Both are in `stringr` package, which is within `library(tidyverse)`

Comment: Thank you. I can run `str_extract(raw, "(?ix) (a|no) \\s+ previous")` and `str_extract(raw, "(?ix) (not \\s+)? receiving")`, but I'm having trouble moving the `str_extract` output into the tibble for all 1,000 observations like your answer does for  age, race, sex, etc, using `tidyr::extract`. I appreciate your patience and help.